# Get a list of commas separated categories inside a loop

Tags: categories, loop

I want to get the list of categories of a post inside the loop. Normally, I would use

```
the_category(', ');
```

But this does output a link, and I only want the category name.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be easy enough i think..

```
<?php 
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    //this would print cat names.. You can arrange in list or whatever you want..
    echo '<span>'.$category->cat_name .'</span>';
} 
?>
```

.
Hope This Helps ;)

Answer (score 4):

Without a loop

```
get_the_category_list(',');
```

Comment: He asks for a list without links, this outputs links as well.

Comment: You could run it through `strip_tags()` to solve the issue of links: `echo strip_tags( get_the_category_list( ', ' ) );`

Answer (score 1):

Below code might help outside the loop. I am using it on `save_post` action hook.

```
// get the assigned terms to the post
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'category' );
// create an empty array for storing category names
$terms_meta = [];
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $terms_meta[] = $term->name;
    }
}

if ( ! empty( $terms_meta ) ) {
    $terms_string = implode( ', ', $terms_meta );
} else {
    $terms_string = '';
}

print_r( $terms_string );
```

Comment: Very good, it works fine for me!